# Parsing URL using Jsoup I've got duplicate URL's

Tags: java, jsoup

I parse specific Url and trying to save all Inner Links (same domain) in allInnerLinks ArrayList and all external Url's in allExternalLinks ArrayList.

```
public void go() {
    Document doc;
    baseUrl = CountLinks.result3;
    try {

        // need http protocol

        doc = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .userAgent(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com").timeout(1000 * 5)
                .ignoreContentType(true).get();
        // get page title
        String title = doc.title();

        // get all links
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

        for (Element link : links) {
            // !!!
            // String absUrl = link.absUrl("href");
            String absUrl = link.attr("abs:href");


            // get the value from href attribute
            if (absUrl.contains(baseUrl)
                    && !(absUrl.contains("mailto"))) {
                allInnerLinks.add(absUrl);
                allInnerLinksCounter++;
            } else {
                allExternalLinks.add(absUrl);
                allExternalLinksCounter++;
            }

        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpStatusException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getUrl());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But at the end I've got duplicate elements. The same URL but Number sign # appears at the end of the link. I can't understand how I get it:

```
PAGEURL                                                     EXTERNAL URLS       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://hostingmaks.com/category/news/                       https://meetings.webex.com/
http://hostingmaks.com/category/news/#                      https://meetings.webex.com/
```

Any reason why it happens?

Comment: `#` refers to a specific bookmark on the page, such as a subsection.  It may make sense for these to be treated separately, as some sites use text afterwords to still control the page (eg `example.com/#!/somePage`).

Comment: @Pokechu22 Actually if I change line String absUrl = link.attr("abs:href"); to String absUrl = link.attr("href");
then everything is fine, no # links. 
But in this case program counts "/docs/example1.doc" as external link which is not true. That's why I use "abs:href" (absolute urls) but I have duplicates instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple method below to check if there is a trailing hashtag/pound sign/number sign that returns a boolean.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public boolean hasHashTag(String url) {
    int index = url.lastIndexOf("#");
    if(index == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(url.substring(index+1));
        System.out.println(url.substring(index+1) + "   "+  (index + 1));
        return !m.find();
    }
}
```

You can now use this method to filter out the duplicates.

```
if(hasHashTag(URLHERE)) {
    //don't add to urls to search
} else {
    //add url to search
}
```